# How can i make ghostsctip command in python work?

Tags: python, subprocess, ghostscript

I am new to python and i have some problem regarding ghostcript command. I have stored some pdf files in a folder and i have already created .txt files for each pdf using pdftotext command. I need to check the size of the file and if it is below a treshold i must remove the txt and run ghostscript command to convert the pdf into a .tif file.
I am using python 3.4 and the code below:

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
      if file.endswith('.txt'):
          num = file.split("_")[0]
          name = file.split("_")[1]
          year = file.split("_")[2].replace('.txt', '')
          size = os.stat(os.path.join(path,file)).st_size

          if size < 2000:
              os.remove(os.path.join(path, file))
              pdf = num +"_"+name+"_"+year
              print(pdf)
              subprocess.check_call(["gs","-q","-dNOPAUSE","-sDEVICE=tiffg4","-r200",
                                  "-dINTERPOLATE","-sPAPERSIZE=a4",
                                  "-sOutputFile="+os.path.join(path, pdf)+"-%00d.tiff",
                                  ""+os.path.join(path, pdf)+""], shell=True)
```

Pdfs files are stored like this 12_C_2014
The above code does not produce any errors. The thing is that the command print(pdf) says that 3 files must be removed but subprocess only works for the first pdf. the other two files remains unttached. 
What changes do i have to do in order to make subprocess to run for every file?
Can anyone help?

Comment: [Don't use a list argument together with shell=True](http://bugs.python.org/issue21347)

Comment: Yeah you are wright to this, but even shell = false doesn't work!By the way i found the solution, what i needed is the parameter -dBATCH which stops the command only if the last pdf file is converted.

Comment: I've pointed out an issue with your code. It doesn't mean that it is the only issue (that is why I've posted it as a comment and not as an answer). If you have found a solution then post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution and i had i little help from @j.F. Sebastian!i hadn't passed the parameter -dBATCH which ends after the end of the last pdf file and the subprocess worked only for the first pdf file. So my code should be like this (in the line where i call the subprocess):

```
subprocess.check_call(["gs",
                       "-q",
                       "-dNOPAUSE",
                       "-dBATCH",
                       "-sDEVICE=tiffg4",
                       "-r200",
                       "-dINTERPOLATE","-sPAPERSIZE=a4",
                       "-sOutputFile="+os.path.join(path, pdf)+"-%00d.tiff",
                       ""+os.path.join(path, pdf)+""], shell=False)
```